# Which insect is this?

Tags: insects

I saw a strange white insect on my lemon plant. Have not seen it earlier. Any idea what it could be? It also has a greenish tinge on its head.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you actually see it moving? I'm not 100% sure, but it might just be an aphid skin. They can look kind of funky after they shed them.

Comment: No idea about the insect in question, but you should do something about your scale infestation!

Comment: @Shule Yes, it was moving. When I reached near it with a twig it hopped to another branch. I saw it hopping and was not crawling or walking at all.

Comment: I think it's a thornbug, or treehopper.  Where are you located?  This could be important in identification.

Comment: @EricDeloak I am located in Kolkata, India. It is the eastern part of the country.

Answer (score 5):

I got to a certain point with the ID, and maybe this is as far as you need.  It's most likely a 'flatid planthopper' nymph. https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=flatid+planthopper&gws_rd=ssl The exact species is beyond me right now.  Perhaps with more time I may be able to get there (actually others may and I will relay the info).  There are many species. Identification at what appears to be a nymph (immature) example is even harder.  Nymphs often have strange waxy tails, and adults often loose them. Regardless, this may be close enough, and this name is used for these insects in agriculture ...  None are beneficial to citrus.  Unless you find an infestation (many many) I would not worry.